# gracefully rejecting RC4 https connections

Tags: asp.net, security, iis, user-experience

Due to security concerns, we are looking at potentially disabling the RC4 cipher on our web server (Windows 2008 R2) and forcing web clients who are connecting with us to use a more secure protocol (AES128 or AES256)

From what I understand, IE8 running on XP doesn't support these better protocols, which would mean we would be cutting off this segment of our user base. (Management is aware of this implication and is ok with it).

My question is...is there a way to configure my site so these rejected Https connections are handled in a user friendly manner? If someone tries to navigate to https://mysite.com and an SSL/TLS negotiation fails, I would assume the end user is going to get some cryptic browser message which would be outside of my control. So I can't tell them that using an alternative browser would resolve the issue.

Comment: This shouldn't be a code issue. This should be an IIS issue.

Comment: I agree. Are you suggesting I move the question to serverfault?

Comment: No, I just suggest solving the problem in the configuration and not in the code. I don't know whether or not serverfault would be the best place for the question.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to change it at the configuration level. Code level is pretty limited, you can read the `HTTPS_KEYSIZE` ServerVariable, but that doesn't tell you what cipher it was... I guess if you made sure that RC4 was the only supported 128-bit cipher that might make it detectable?